# Scala Spark model transform returns all zeroes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-ml

Good time of the day,everyone. To start with i'm doing simple machine learning task with apache-spark ml(not mllib) and scala. My build.sbt as follows :

```
name := "spark"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core"  % "2.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.8.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.0.1"
```

All stages doing just fine. But there problem with dataset which should contain predictions. In my case i'm doing classification on three classes, the lables are `1.0, 2.0, 3.0`, but prediction column contains only of `0.0` labels, even though there is no such label at all. 
Here is original dataframe :

```
+--------------------+--------+
|               tfIdf|estimate|
+--------------------+--------+
|(3000,[0,1,8,14,1...|     3.0|
|(3000,[0,1707,223...|     3.0|
|(3000,[1,24,33,64...|     3.0|
|(3000,[1,40,114,5...|     2.0|
|(3000,[1,363,743,...|     2.0|
|(3000,[2,20,65,88...|     3.0|
|(3000,[3,15,21,23...|     3.0|
|(3000,[3,45,53,14...|     3.0|
|(3000,[3,387,433,...|     1.0|
|(3000,[3,523,629,...|     3.0|
+--------------------+--------+
```

And after classification, my predictions are :

```
+--------------------+--------+----------+
|               tfIdf|estimate|prediction|
+--------------------+--------+----------+
|(3000,[0,1,8,14,1...|     3.0|       0.0|
|(3000,[0,1707,223...|     3.0|       0.0|
|(3000,[1,24,33,64...|     3.0|       0.0|
|(3000,[1,40,114,5...|     2.0|       0.0|
|(3000,[1,363,743,...|     2.0|       0.0|
|(3000,[2,20,65,88...|     3.0|       0.0|
|(3000,[3,15,21,23...|     3.0|       0.0|
|(3000,[3,45,53,14...|     3.0|       0.0|
|(3000,[3,387,433,...|     1.0|       0.0|
|(3000,[3,523,629,...|     3.0|       0.0|
+--------------------+--------+----------+
```

And my code as follows :

```
 val toDouble = udf[Double, String](_.toDouble)
  val kribrumData = krData.withColumn("estimate", toDouble(krData("estimate")))
    .select($"text",$"estimate")

  kribrumData.cache()

  val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
    .setInputCol("text")
    .setOutputCol("tokens")
  val stopWordsRemover = new StopWordsRemover()
    .setInputCol("tokens")
    .setOutputCol("filtered")
    .setStopWords(STOP_WORDS)
  val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
    .setInputCol("filtered")
    .setNumFeatures(3000)
    .setOutputCol("tf")
  val idf = new IDF()
    .setInputCol("tf")
    .setOutputCol("tfIdf")
  val preprocessor = new Pipeline()
    .setStages(Array(tokenizer,stopWordsRemover,hashingTF,idf))
  val preprocessor_model = preprocessor.fit(kribrumData)

  val preprocessedKribrumData = preprocessor_model.transform(kribrumData)
    .select("tfIdf", "estimate")

  var Array(train, test) = preprocessedKribrumData.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed = 7)

  test.show(10)

  val logisticRegressor = new LogisticRegression()
    .setMaxIter(10)
    .setRegParam(0.3)
    .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
    .setLabelCol("estimate")
    .setFeaturesCol("tfIdf")
  val classifier = new OneVsRest()
    .setLabelCol("estimate")
    .setFeaturesCol("tfIdf")
    .setClassifier(logisticRegressor)


  val model = classifier.fit(train)

  val predictions = model.transform(test)

  predictions.show(10)

  val evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
    .setMetricName("accuracy").setLabelCol("estimate")

  val accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)

  println("Classification accuracy" + accuracy.toString)
```

This code eventually inspires prediction accuracy equals to zero(because there are no label "0.0" in target column "estimate"). So, what actually am i doing wrong? Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out the problem. Spark does not throws error or exception, when label field is double, but labels are not in a valid range for classifier, to overcome this usage of StringIndexer is reuired, so we just need to add in pipeline :

```
val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("estimate")
  .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
```

This step solves the problem, however it is inconvinient.